# An efficient way to check the inboxes of a large number of email accounts constantly

Tags: email, imap

I wonder how those email management apps (such as [Mailbox](http://www.mailboxapp.com/)) keep checking the inboxes of a large number of email accounts constantly. Do they keep an IMAP connection with the server for each account by sending the IDLE command? It seems to me that this will need a lot of resources by keeping a large number of connections. Is there any more efficient way?

Comment: I do not think you can do this 'efficiently' using IMAP.  IMAP uses one connection per user, per folder, and generally does not allow you to reauthenticate on a given connection.  Perhaps they cycle through every 15 minutes or so.  But you're right, maintaining IDLE for many accounts does use a lot of connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065164/automatic-imap-connection-kill-script/16066325#16066325 -- now removed, but available through the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130510142802/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065164/automatic-imap-connection-kill-script).

It is, unfortunately, a pretty wide-spread misconception that "a lot of connections" implies "using a lot of resources", but unless both you and your target servers support the `NOTIFY` extension, there isn't anything better than `IDLE` that you could use.